# show ionic loader in between the process of ng-repeat rendering data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

This question my seems silly to you but i just want to know that is it possible to show ionic loader in between the process of rendering data in dropdown by ng-repeat.I goggled and found two directives one is for after-render and other is for on-finish-render both works good but i am really confused that how can i show and hide my ionic loader during this whole process.

here is some of my code :-

```html
<label class="item item-input"> <select class="input-select"
   ng-model="user.country.value"
   ng-change="selectedCountry(user.country.value)">
    <option ng-selected="country.value==user.country.value"
     ng-repeat="country in results"  value="{{country.value}}">
     {{country.name}}</option>
    <option value="" disabled hidden>{{'checkoutPage.country' |
     translate}}</option>
  </select>
  </label>

 <label class="item item-input" ng-if="showDropDownInStateLabel()">
   <select class="input-select" ng-model="userState.states.region_id"
   ng-change="selectedState(userState.states.region_id)">
    <option ng-selected="states.region_id==userState.states.region_id" ng-repeat="states in StatesArray" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished"  
     value="{{states}}">{{states.name}}</option>
    <option value="" disabled hidden>{{'checkoutPage.state' |
     translate}}</option>
  </select>
  </label>
```

here is directive :-

```js
app.directive('onFinishRender', function($timeout) {
 return {
  restrict : 'A',
  link : function(scope, element, attr) {
   if (scope.$last === true) {
    $timeout(function() {
     scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
    });
   }
  }
 }
});
```

here is the listener for event:-

```js
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(
       ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
      alert("rendering ends here");
     });
```

can any one tell me that how to show loader to user when ng-repeat rendering the data in dropdown.I even try by making two different functions for showloader() and hideloader() . showLoader i call when user select some value in dropdown and hideLoader gets call in $scope.$on function.

Actually i am having two dropdowns one is for countries and other is for their respective states.When user select country that state dropdown got visible to user.this whole process took some time in rendering which make application looks like hanged to user so i just want to display user a loader to avoid this illusion.

here is the function which finds which country have states array and according to which stats dropdown got visible to user :-

```html
$scope.user = {};
     $scope.selectedCountry = function(value) {
      // alert(value);
      $scope.data.region = '';
      if (angular.isString(LocalStorage
        .getData("StateSelected"))) {
       LocalStorage.setData("StateSelected", "");
       LocalStorage.setData("Statename", "");
      }

      if (angular.isString(LocalStorage
        .getData("Addressregion"))) {
       LocalStorage.setData("Addressregion", "");

      }
      $scope.user.country_id = value;
      LocalStorage.setData("CountrySelected", value);

      for ( var c = 0; c < LocalStorage
        .getObject("getCountriesresult").length; c++) {
       if (value == LocalStorage
         .getObject("getCountriesresult")[c].value) {
        if (LocalStorage
          .getObject("getCountriesresult")[c].state.length > 0) {
         shouldShowDropdown = true;
         $scope.StatesArray = LocalStorage
           .getObject("getCountriesresult")[c].state;
        } else {
         shouldShowDropdown = false;
        }
       }

      }

     }
```

Any help will be appreciated, 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of feature should never take so long to execute.

I think you should try to remove the huge amount of LocalStorage access inside loops. From what I saw, you can do everything you want using local variables (in-memory).

$ionicLoading works fine for async calls that take time, like an AJAX call.